# Can we add targeted cross-stackexchange promotions?

Tags: feature-request

Seems to me that ui.stackexchange.com is a great place for programmers and other stackexchange sites to ask UI people stuff. So how about a promotion on stackoverflow and other sister sites? Anyone know whether this can be done?

Comment: See also blog entry for May 31st http://blog.stackoverflow.com/ - I've requested one for ux.stackexchange.

Answer (score 1):

Done.

They're called house ads and they on any of our sites currently hosting ads (Stack Overflow, Server Fault, and Super User).